I want to deploy multiple resources each in a different resource group in one ARM template
I want to deploy multi resources in a each different resource group in one ARM template like below.

But I have no idea how should I write deploy code in Azure CLI or PowerShell.
BTW, I wrote target subscription ID and resource group name in ARM template like below.
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
      "name": "strageAccount",
      "subscriptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "resourceGroup": "RG-compute",
      "properties": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
      "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
      "name": "privateEndpointBlob",
      "subscriptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "resourceGroup": "RG-network",
      "properties": {}
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}

I read this MS reference but I couldn't understand very well.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-resource-group?tabs=azure-cli
If you have any idea, please tell me.
Any other would be helped.
Thank you.

Here is a sample which show how to deploy two storage account to two different resource group. It works well, and much similar to your case. The changes you need to make is to add additional resource type in module such as private endpoint, etc. hope this can help.
Two key things, Get reference here

module in bicep
scope in bicep

storage.bicep
param storageLocation string
param storageName string

resource storageAcct 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-04-01' = {
  name: storageName
  location: storageLocation
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
  properties: {}
}

main.bicep
@maxLength(11)
param storagePrefix string = ''

param firstStorageLocation string 
param firstResourceGroup string

param secondResourceGroup string
param secondStorageLocation string

var firstStorageName = '${storagePrefix}${uniqueString(firstResourceGroup)}'
var secondStorageName = '${storagePrefix}${uniqueString(secondResourceGroup)}'

module firstStorageAcct 'storage.bicep' = {
  name: 'storageModule1'
  scope: resourceGroup(firstResourceGroup)
  params: {
    storageLocation: firstStorageLocation
    storageName: firstStorageName
  }
}

module secondStorageAcct 'storage.bicep' = {
  name: 'storageModule2'
  scope: resourceGroup(secondResourceGroup)
  params: {
    storageLocation: secondStorageLocation
    storageName: secondStorageName
  }
}


deploy.ps1
$paramObject = @{
    storagePrefix = ''
    firstStorageLocation = 'eastus' 
    firstResourceGroup = 'wb-test1-rg'
    secondStorageLocation = 'eastus'
    secondResourceGroup = 'wb-test2-rg'
}


$deploymentName = 'wbtest'
$rgName = 'wb-test1-rg'  ## any resource group in current subscription works.

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deploymentName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile 'main.bicep' -TemplateParameterObject $paramObject


using bicep in complex case instead of Json arm template, which will make you more efficient


main.json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storagePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "maxLength": 11
    },
    "firstStorageLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "firstResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "secondResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "secondStorageLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "firstStorageName": "[format('{0}{1}', parameters('storagePrefix'), uniqueString(parameters('firstResourceGroup')))]",
    "secondStorageName": "[format('{0}{1}', parameters('storagePrefix'), uniqueString(parameters('secondResourceGroup')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "name": "storageModule1",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('firstResourceGroup')]",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "inner"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {
          "storageLocation": {
            "value": "[parameters('firstStorageLocation')]"
          },
          "storageName": {
            "value": "[variables('firstStorageName')]"
          }
        },
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "metadata": {
            "_generator": {
              "name": "bicep",
              "version": "0.27.1.19265",
              "templateHash": "5642662840380359784"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "storageLocation": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "storageName": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
              "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
              "location": "[parameters('storageLocation')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
              },
              "kind": "Storage",
              "properties": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "name": "storageModule2",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('secondResourceGroup')]",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "inner"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {
          "storageLocation": {
            "value": "[parameters('secondStorageLocation')]"
          },
          "storageName": {
            "value": "[variables('secondStorageName')]"
          }
        },
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "metadata": {
            "_generator": {
              "name": "bicep",
              "version": "0.27.1.19265",
              "templateHash": "5642662840380359784"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "storageLocation": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "storageName": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
              "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
              "location": "[parameters('storageLocation')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
              },
              "kind": "Storage",
              "properties": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Thank you for information but I should use json because of our company policy... Do you have any idea of json?

we can use bicep build main.bicep help convert bicep to json arm template.

I have already converted it, and attached it in the response. Just check and have a try.
